# How to patch jar file in java?

Tags: java, path, jar, classloader

For test purpose I need to substitute .jar file with my own.
Does it possible set test.jar (the same name) previous on other test.jar?
Will classloader load only first find jar?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Java interpreter will look for classes in the directories in the order they appear in the class path variable.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html

**Edit:** So you can put you jar first in the classpath to overrider the existing jar.